# How to cap network traffic using TCP/IP settings in Windows 7?

Tags: networking, tcpip

Is it possible to cap network traffic on a Windows 7 system so that it will not exceed a given throughput value?  The BitTorrent client uTorrent is able to do this, but I am guessing that it's doing it by monitoring the throughput itself.  What I would like to be able to do is set an upper limit for the system at the OS level so that overall network traffic can be limited.  I am more interested in restricting downloads, but a solution for overall traffic will be just as useful.

Comment: PS: It seems that this falls under the topic of "trafic shaping", something that I had looked into under Linux about four years back, and at the time there was not much information on it, and I was unable to even get started on the topic.  I am glad to know there is an equivalent capability in the Windows world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not possible with stadnard settings. There is QOS that could possibly be used, but this is an API to my knowledge, not a setting.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959580.aspx (Generic QoS API)

Comment: Thank you.  I needed a definitive answer and this was it.  Also, the link you provided has guided me into the correct domain (Winsock 2) to investigate further.

Answer (score 2):

Is this system connected to a managed switch? If that's the case, you could apply a cap directly through the switch.

If not, you could try these programs:

- netlimiter.com
- bandwidthcontroller.com

Here's a free version of BandwidthLimiter. Apparently it works on Windows 7 as well.
http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html

Comment: Thank you.  The system is connected to a ZyXel ADSL gateway modem but I am not sure if its interface allows for much control.  However, the links look promising (and I was unaware of these products).  Microsoft has something called a File Transfer Manager that I am using, but specifying an upper limit with its GUI is worthless, it still maxes out all available bandwidth when doing MSDN subscription downloads, and that negatively affects other users on the LAN.  Much appreciated.